# three selects each based on previous jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I'm trying to do 3 selects in cakePhp + jQuery first one with provinces, second - localities, third - schools in that place. Here is my cake code (so far):

```
           echo $this->Form->input('proviences', array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'empty' => true,
                'options' => $proviences,
                'label' => 'Province',
                'class' => 'proviences',
                'before' => '<div style="float:left;width:180px"',
                'after' => "</div>"
            ));

            echo $this->Form->input('localities', array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'empty' => true,
                'options' => $localities,
                'label' => 'City',
                'class' => 'localities',
                'before' => '<div style="float:left;width:180px"',
                'after' => "</div>"
            ));
            $schoolList = array();
            foreach($schools as $value) {
                $schoolsList[]=$value['name'];
            }
            echo $this->Form->input('school_id', array(
                'label' => 'Szkoła',
                'options' => $schoolsList,
                'empty' => true,
                'before' => '<div style="float:left;width:240px"',
                'after' => "</div>",
                'onchange' => "submit();",
            ));
```

In $schools i have a list looking this way

```
array(
   id1 => array(
         'name' => 'some_name',
         'province' => 'some_province',
         'locality' => 'some_city'
         )
)
```

and using this to get lists of provinces,localities and school names
I was trying to use this but couldn't get it working ;/
[Filter three select boxes based on previous selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602535/filter-three-select-boxes-based-on-previous-selections)
Is there a way of doing it in jQuery without ajax?

Comment: you can do it without using ajax, but for that you would need the `schools` array on client side, and create/edit options based on that on the client side, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it without using ajax, but for that you would need the schools array on client side, and create/edit options based on that on the client side, too.

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SatjQ/). (hastily thrown together, but you get the idea). You need to get the `schools` array into js, though. you could either use AJAX for that or, pass it as json on the page:

```
echo 'var schools = JSON.parse('.json_encode($schools).');
```

You have to think about where to place that, too, so that the variable doesn't leak into the global scope. you could put it in the jQuery closure, for example:

```
echo '(function($){';
echo 'var schools = JSON.parse('.json_encode($schools).');

// now the javascript from the fiddle...

echo '}(jQuery))';
```